# `iOS App with Watch App` vs the new `Watch App` option in Xcode 11

Tags: watchkit, watchos

With Xcode 11, the 2nd option is new and I can't find explanation for these questions:

1. I have an existing iOS app with companion Watch app. Will my companion Watch app be searchable like a standalone one on the Watch AppStore with this option?
2. Is there any advantage of re-writing my companion Watch app from scratch using the 2nd option? How can Apple tell that this standalone Watch app is related to my iOS app?
3. How do I publish a standalone Watch app on AppStoreConnect? I don't see a standalone Watch app option?
4. If I decide to rewrite, how do I go about doing this? Should I remove my companion Watch app from my iOS app, then publish a standalone Watch app?

Is there a right documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decouple your previous watchOS app by going to the project navigator, selecting your WatchKit Extension target, then checking "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation."

If you don't make it standalone, the companion Apple Watch app will still be searchable on the watchOS App Store. I'm currently running watchOS 6 beta, and see all the previous apps in the watchOS App Store that depend on an iOS app including my own. Developers aren't able to ship standalone watchOS 6 apps until watchOS 6 is released to the public in the Fall.

- [watchOS 6 part of the Platforms State of the Union](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-103/?time=2556)
- [Creating Independent Watch Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/208/)